# webcam does not report higher resolutions on windows-10

Tags: windows-10, webcam, 4k-resolution, directshow

BRIO 4K Stream webcam does not report higher resolutions on windows-10-pro machine while on windows-10-home machine everything works ok.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue ?

What i have tried so far:

1. Take webcam driver from working machine and install on problematic
   machine
2. Update windows to latest version
3. Use windows-media-foundation API to list modes instead of directshow
4. Google for logitech brio specific issues and anything related that came into my mind
5. Opened issue on logitech support site
6. Connected usb3 hub before webcam
7. Tried every USB port on motherboard
8. Connected camera to usb3.0 port on Geforce RTC 2070 via USB-c to USB-c cable

Problematic machine info and FFMPEG command:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~3501 Mhz
Total Physical Memory:     65,360 MB
Hotfix(s):                 6 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4506991
                           [02]: KB4497165
                           [03]: KB4498523
                           [04]: KB4503308
                           [05]: KB4508433
                           [06]: KB4505903

ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -list_options true -i video="BRIO 4K Stream Edition"
ffmpeg version N-94455-g01994c93db Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190716
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.100 / 58. 55.100
  libavformat    58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.100 /  7. 58.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
....
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
....
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=60.0002
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x896 fps=5 max s=1600x896 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x896 fps=5 max s=1600x896 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000018a9fa09600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=30
video=BRIO 4K Stream Edition: Immediate exit requested
```

Correct output on different machine:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~3696 Mhz
Total Physical Memory:     16,308 MB
Hotfix(s):                 2 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4508433
                           [02]: KB4505903

ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -list_options true -i video="BRIO 4K Stream Edition"
ffmpeg version N-94452-g9af8ce754b Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190716
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.100 / 58. 55.100
  libavformat    58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.100 /  7. 58.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
....
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=90.0001
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x896 fps=5 max s=1600x896 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x896 fps=5 max s=1600x896 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=2560x1440 fps=5 max s=2560x1440 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=2560x1440 fps=5 max s=2560x1440 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=3840x2160 fps=5 max s=3840x2160 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=3840x2160 fps=5 max s=3840x2160 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=4096x2160 fps=5 max s=4096x2160 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=4096x2160 fps=5 max s=4096x2160 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=640x360 fps=5 max s=640x360 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=640x360 fps=5 max s=640x360 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000021ea7d28580]   pixel_format=nv12  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=30
video=BRIO 4K Stream Edition: Immediate exit requested
```

Please note additinal `s=1920x1080 fps=60` and `s=4096x2160 fps=30` modes not present in problematic output.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I assume you have tried the cam on all usb ports to see if that changes available resolutions?

Comment: @Moab yes tried each one, 10 usb ports total of which 5 are blue marked USB3.0 . MB being Gigabyte GA-X99-UD4 .

Comment: I would contact Logitech support about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BRIO 4K Stream webcam requires USB 3.1 port to report UHD resolutions.

I tested `PEX-U31-01 Gembird 2-port USB 3.1 PCI-Express add-on card`

[image]

Don't forget to connect SATA power cable

[image]

When connected to `PEX-U31-01` card camera reports UHD modes:

```
[dshow @ 000001a82352a840]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=2560x1440 fps=5 max s=2560x1440 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001a82352a840]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=2560x1440 fps=5 max s=2560x1440 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001a82352a840]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=3840x2160 fps=5 max s=3840x2160 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001a82352a840]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=3840x2160 fps=5 max s=3840x2160 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001a82352a840]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=4096x2160 fps=5 max s=4096x2160 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001a82352a840]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=4096x2160 fps=5 max s=4096x2160 fps=30
```

Problem is that capture does not work for 1080p and higher resolutions with `PEX-U31-01` card. `Logitech Capture` application shows `Camera not connected` message. FFMPEG does not receive the frame.